# I want to show the Default pic to the user profile whenever a new user is registered using Signals without doing it manually from Django admin

Tags: python, django

I want to load the default pic of the user, whenever a new user is created using signals. But its not loading the default pic. I don't want to do this manually from Django admin, I want this to be done whenever a new user is created in the app.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class userprofile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    profilepic = models.ImageField(default='pp.png',upload_to='profile_pic',blank = True)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import userprofile



class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = userprofile
        fields = ['profilepic',]
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def profile(request):    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST,request.FILES,instance=request.user.userprofile)
        if p_form.is_valid():
            p_form.save()        
            return render(request,'profile.html')
    else:
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.user)

    context = {
        'p_form': p_form        
        }

    return render(request,'profile.html',context)
```

**profile.html**

```
<form method ="POST" class="sm:w-1/3 text-center sm:pr-8 sm:py-8" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
            {% csrf_token %}
            <img id="profile_pic" alt="team" class="flex-shrink-0 rounded-lg w-full h-56 object-cover object-center mb-4" src="{{user.userprofile.profilepic.url}}">
            {{ p_form|crispy }}
            <br>
            <input id="file-input" style="padding: 8px 93px;" class="text-white bg-green-500 border-0 py-2 px-8 focus:outline-none hover:bg-green-700 rounded text-lg" type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

**signalspy**

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import userprofile


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        userprofile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

**apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class HomepageConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'Homepage'


    def ready(self):
        import users.signals
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing load the image outside the form. Then add the default image inside media and outside the folder where you upload the profile picture.[image]

As you can see it is inside the root of media folder.